# Is there another way of converting of string digit to integer digit using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is there another way of converting of digits of string to integers? I currently experience my condition is not working when I try to determine if the digit is less than 0 or greater than 0.

**GOAL:** I want to determine if the digits is less than 0 or greater than 0

I have value of **-0.01%** from database
so when i try to check the condition says that the value is not less than 0.

```
    <?php 

     if(intval($flash_p_and_l_load_data->ads_percentage) < 0) {
        // echo '<td bgcolor="#FFC7CE" style="text-align: center; width: 7%;">'.$flash_p_and_l_load_data->dtc_percentage.'</td>';
        echo 'less than 0';
     }
     else {
        // echo '<td bgcolor="#C6EFCE" style="text-align: center; width: 7%; ">'.$flash_p_and_l_load_data->dtc_percentage.'</td>';
        echo 'greater than 0';
     } 

?>
```

Comment: The integer value of -0.01 isn't less than zero, though. It is zero. If you do the comparison without intval, PHP will convert the string to a number automatically, and -0.01 will evaluate as less than zero.

Comment: @Don'tPanic why the echo shows that. -0.01 is greater than 0

Comment: Because you're using `intval()`, and `0` is not `< 0`.

Comment: even i remove the inval() convertion. still the output is greater than 0

Comment: Interesting, and not what I expected. (See https://3v4l.org/bl84d) Can you edit the question to show the output of `var_dump($flash_p_and_l_load_data-> ads_percentage)`?

Comment: string(4) "-0.0"  the output of var_dump

Comment: Hmm, what happened to the 1?

Comment: @Don'tPanic sorry for not including the script. why the 1 is not on the value. is because on my script FORMAT(ROUND((SUM(ns) / SUM(tgt_di_ns + tgt_to_ns + tgt_dt_ns + tgt_dl_ns +  tgt_std_ns) - 1),1),1) as ads_percentage

Comment: I see. I think the solution is to do the < 0 comparison before formatting the number.

Comment: what do you mean for that ? thanks

Comment: I mean, if you need to compare the number to zero, you can't round/format before doing that, or you may remove the part of the number that differentiates it from zero, as is the case here.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yah maybe you are correct now. but why it happens.?

Comment: You're rounding the number to one decimal place, so 0.01 is rounded to 0.0. My advice is to remove the FORMAT and ROUND functions from that expression in your query, and just return the result of the calculation. You can do the formatting and rounding in PHP after you check that the number against zero.

Comment: maybe that is one way of correcting my problem.. but thanks again panic for helping me..

Comment: @Don'tPanic  +100 for patience